# How does one compile single file Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4, compilation, usability

While I used to compile a single source file with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in prior versions of Xcode, how does one do the same in Xcode 4? (Note that this is different than preprocessing or showing the disassembly of the file.) If compiling from a command line is proposed then it must be such that the project's settings, include paths, preprocessor definitions, etc., are all included.

An example use case is where I make a header file change but only want to test the change's effect with respect to a single source file, not all of the files that depend upon that header.

Comment: Since it appears Apple has completely removed this feature from Xcode 4, I think the only way we'll get it back is to make an Xcode plug-in. Unfortunately, the plug-in API isn't documented and Apple hasn't made any statements about opening it up anytime soon.

Comment: i have the same problem. i like using this sort of thing as a method for porting - i bring over the files from another platform and build them to see where the errors are i need to fix on a per-file basis.

Comment: You should accept John Stephen's answer.

Answer (score 13):

The command has been moved to the Perform Action submenu.  Look under

```
Product > Perform Action > Compile filename.cpp
```

To assign <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to it, go to

```
File > Preferences > Key Bindings > Product Menu group
```

and you'll find Compile File where you can assign a key.  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is assigned to Clear Console now by default, so be sure to remove that binding to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 7):

One way that I have found to do this is to using the following menu commands:

```
Product -> Generate Output -> Generate Preprocessed File
Product -> Generate Output -> Generate Assembly File
```

This may not be exactly what you want, but it will compile the single file.

Comment: In Xcode 5 you have `Product -> Perform Action -> Compile "filename.cpp"` (make sure the source file is selected and added to the active target).

Answer (score -1):

When you build a project, xcode runs compilation command. You can check the log, search for your file and copy paste that command on Terminal. It'll compile only the file for which you copy/pasted on the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

If your file is C (or C++) file, then simply open your terminal, go to the folder in which the file resides and type

```
gcc -o outputFile inputFile.c
```

I am not familar with Objective-c that much, but GCC **might** work since it's only a superset of C, just like C++.

Hope that was helpful :)

Comment: Not really what he asked for and yes, gcc can compile it as long objective C support is compiled in and necessary library includes are provided.

Answer (score -2):

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on Xcode 3 and before has been remapped to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Xcode 4

Along the same lines, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> was remapped to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (in case you ever used that)

Comment: Compiling a single file is not the same as building the whole project.

Comment: @fbrereto I think oey192 realizes that, but people with 1 karma can't post comments.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I see; I didn't get that impression as Cmd+K (compile a single source file in Xcode 3) isn't the same operation as building the whole project (Cmd+B on both Xcode 3 and 4.) Maybe I'm just reading his answer wrong...

Comment: The way I understand it, he's pointing out that the previous keyboard shortcut, even if it appears to work, doesn't because it's been remapped to solution build.

Answer (score -3):

The common requirement for single file compilation is checking it for syntax errors. (atleast for me). Since xcode4 highlights syntax errors as you type. It seems apple removed that feature.

Comment: Compiling a single file is about a lot more than syntax errors. Among other things it will show you whether that file has its dependencies declared adequately.